# How to get the first element of Set in ES6 ( EcmaScript 2015)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES6, how do we quickly get the element?

in [MDN Syntax for Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), I didn't find an answer for it.

Comment: What do you consider the "first"?

Comment: "Set objects are collections of values. You can iterate through the elements of a set in insertion order." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 142, accepted):

They don't seem to expose the List to be accessible from the instanced Object. This is from the EcmaScript Draft:

> 23.2.4 Properties of Set Instances
>
> Set instances are ordinary objects that inherit properties from the Set prototype. Set instances also have a [[SetData]] internal slot.

[[SetData]] is the list of values the Set is holding.

A possible solution (and a somewhat expensive one) is to grab an iterator and then call `next()` for the first value:

```js
var x = new Set();
x.add(1);
x.add({ a: 2 });
//get iterator:
var it = x.values();
//get first entry:
var first = it.next();
//get value out of the iterator entry:
var value = first.value;
console.log(value); //1
```

Worth mentioning too:

```js
Set.prototype.values === Set.prototype.keys
```

Comment: Btw, iterators are considered pretty *in*expensive, that approach is quite optimal…

Comment: Not saying iterators are suboptimal or expensive, is just that if you got to create an iterator just to grab a hold of the first element of the list, then that sounds expensive, as opposed to just access the element directly.

Comment: or in one line theset.values().next().value

Comment: Why javascript does not provide a method for finding a specific element within the set? Is there any reasonable reason for that?

Comment: @AZSH there is a way to find a specific element in a javascript set. It's `theset.has(x)`. What you can't do in a set is retrieve an item by index, since sets are unordered. What javascript is missing is a way to retrieve any item from a set easily. That's what this answer is trying to provide.

Comment: Sets actually *are ordered*. The documentation mentions multiple times that you can integrate over the values/entries in insertion order. Since sets internally keep this knowledge, it would be nice if you could easily get item at index `n`.

Comment: Another one-liner: `[...theSet][0]`

Comment: If you want to use this with all your sets then you can do:

`Set.prototype.first = function(){return this.values().next().value;};`

after this:

`anyset.first()`

will give you the first element

Comment: Another nice one, using array destructuring: `const [first] = theSet;`

Comment: A little bit of experimental performance data. Method 1: `first = set.values().next().value`. Method 2: `first = [...set][0]`. Method 3: `[first] = set`. Methods 1 and 3 are basically O(1) (about 15 million iterations per second in chrome, 1.5 million in firefox regardless of set size). Method 2 is O(n), scaling with n along a ratio at roughly 1s / 300'000'000 for chrome and 10 times slower for firefox. Don't use Method 2 (`first = [...set][0]`) unless your sets are very very small: it's much costlier than the other methods.

Comment: @ichigolas Sets keeping insertion order does *not* mean that sets keep their elements in an indexed structure - especially given an `O(1)` delete operation. Getting item at index `n` would quite likely have `O(n)` time complexity.

Answer (score 25):

### there are many solutions

1. `for...of` loop

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add(2);
set.add(3);

// return the first item of Set ✅
function getFirstItemOfSet(set) {
  for(let item of set) {
    if(item) {
       return item;
    }   
  }
  return undefined;
}

const first = getFirstItemOfSet(set);
console.log('first item =', first);
```

2. `destructuring assignment`

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add(2);
set.add(3);

// only get the first item ✅
const [first] = set;
console.log('first item =', first, typeof first);
// first item = 2 number
```

3. `...spread` operator

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add(2);
set.add(3);

// convert Set to Array ✅
const first = [...set][0];
console.log('first item =', first);
```

4. `iterator` & `next()`

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add(2);
set.add(3);

// iterator ✅
const first = set.keys().next().value;
console.log(`first item =`, first);

// OR
set.values().next().value;

// OR
set.entries().next().value[0];
// OR
set.entries().next().value[1];
```

### refs

https://www.cnblogs.com/xgqfrms/p/16564519.html

Comment: Result of operation 2. is a set, not just the value.

Comment: @randomuser Have you tried running my code snippet? It's the number type value in my solution 2.

Comment: Why the `if` in the `for` loop?

Comment: The spread operator to convert the whole thing into an array is very inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

```js
let s = new Set([2,3,4])

let [head] = s

console.log(head)
```

simplified from @rodo's version

Answer (score 2):

A more direct way to get the first element from a Set (works for arrays too):

```
const mySet = new Set(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
const [firstElement, secondElement, thirdElement] = mySet

console.log(thirdElement, firstElement, secondElement) // baz foo bar
```

Comment: The most simple and elegant by far! Not to mention that it keeps the type in TypeScript, compared to the iterator solutions which results in `any`.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant and practical solution I have found is by **retrieving the first IteratorResult and acquiring its value** `set.values().next().value`.

```
const set = new Set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);   
const first = set.values().next().value; // first will be equal to 0
```

Answer (score 2):

most simple way:

```js
const data=new Set(['1', '2', '3']);

const first = [...data][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another choice will be to use the `for..of` loop like so:

```js
const mySet = new Set(["one", "two", 3]);
for (let item of mySet) {
    console.log(item);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the iterator on the `Set<T>`:

```
const mySet = new Set<string>(['one', 'two', 'three']);
const firstValue = mySet.values().next().value;
console.log(firstValue);
```

You could also covert it to an array and then use normal indexing:

```
const mySet = new Set<string>(['one', 'two', 'three']);
const firstValue = Array.from(mySet)[0];
console.log(firstValue);
```

The first way is better from a complexity standpoint because it doesn't have to create a new array.

Answer (score 0):

**Using spread syntax (...):**

```
const mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const firstElement = [...mySet][0];
console.log(firstElement); // Output: 1
```

**Use destructuring**

```
const set = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
const [first] = set;
console.log(first); // Output: 1

const set = new Set([1, 2, 3]);

const [, second] = set;
console.log(second); // 2
```

**Using Set.values():**

```
const mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const firstElement = mySet.values().next().value;
console.log(firstElement); // Output: 1
```

**Using for...of loop:**

```
const mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
let firstElement;
for (const element of mySet) {
    firstElement = element;
    break;
}
console.log(firstElement); // Output: 1
```