# Printing particular element of set container in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I want to fetch a particular element from set container.
Here is my source code:

```js
var i, item, val = '';
var setObj1 = new Set();

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setObj1.add(i);
}

for (item of setObj1.values()) {
  val += item + ' ';
}

document.getElementById('demo').textContent = "The set values are: " + val;
document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = "The set value at index 2 is: " + setObj1.values[1];
```

```html
<div id="demo"> </div>
<div id="demo1"> </div>
```

Please correct my syntax or suggest me a approach to print particular index value of set.

Comment: Nothing to do with HTML5. *Set* was first added to EMCAScript 2015 (edition 6).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the first element of Set in ES6 ( EcmaScript 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539354/how-to-get-the-first-element-of-set-in-es6-ecmascript-2015)

Comment: @adiga, The above link only to fetch first elemnt of set, my query was to fetch any element of set. So not duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
   var i, item,val = '';
   var setObj1 = new Set();

   for(i=0;i<5;i++){
     setObj1.add(i);
   }

   for (item of setObj1.values()){
     val+=item + ' '; 
   }

   var iterator = setObj1.values();
   iterator.next();   

   document.getElementById('demo').textContent = "The set values are: "+val;
   document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = "The set value at index 2 is: "+ iterator.next().value;
```

Note: If you want to get values with their index it would be better to use arrays instead of `Set`

Comment: What If I want to fetch 3rd or 4th index value only?

Comment: then you should use an array, Sets are used with iterators

Comment: Inorder to avoid duplicate element I used set, so need to use set conatiner at any how.

Comment: After you build your set, you can convert it to an array `var array = Array.from(setObj1);`

Answer (score 2):

Although you *can* do that, it's expensive. Sets aren't for index-oriented or key-oriented operations (use an array or Map for that).

The expensive way is to converting the set to an array (which uses `values` indirectly through the set's iterator and iterates all the way to the end to get the full set) and index into the array:

```
document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = [...setObj1][1];
```

Live Example:

```js
var i, item, val = '';
var setObj1 = new Set();

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setObj1.add(i);
}

for (item of setObj1.values()) {
  val += item + ' ';
}

document.getElementById('demo').textContent = "The set values are: " + val;
document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = "The set value at index 2 is: " + [...setObj1][1];
```

```html
<div id="demo"> </div>
<div id="demo1"> </div>
```

But here's your example using an array instead:

```js
var i, item, val = '';
var values = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  values[i] = i;
}

document.getElementById('demo').textContent = "The set values are: " + values.join(" ");
document.getElementById('demo1').innerHTML = "The set value at index 2 is: " + values[1];
```

```html
<div id="demo"> </div>
<div id="demo1"> </div>
```

Comment: ,I don't want to convert into array for both of your solution.

Comment: @Arya - You should use the correct data structure for what you're doing. Set is not the correct data structure for this.