# Access the first insertion in Set

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

I recently found out that Sets in JS (ES6) is an ordered data structure. That is, it retains the insertion order. I am wondering, if this is the case, how to fetch the first inserted data in set without having to use an Iterable. And what is the purpose of such an implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the first element of Set in ES6 ( EcmaScript 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539354/how-to-get-the-first-element-of-set-in-es6-ecmascript-2015)

Comment: The purpose? Well, if I had to guess I'd say that the tc39ers learned from objects: objects were unordered, then a few engines did have an order, people started relying on it, and at the end it was specified to get ahead of the chaos.

Comment: "*without having to use an Iterable.*" - what's wrong with that?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to access the first element of a set the way we access for arrays, directly. I have an understanding that iterable has a memory overhead (please correct me if I am wrong). Also, since sets/maps are hashed, i was wondering why they are made ordered (doesn't this again come with a memory overhead?)