# Javascript Set - Fastest way to get any value?

Tags: javascript

I have a Set. I would like to get any value out of the set.

What is the fastest way to retrieve any item from the Set?

At the moment I am converting the Set to an array, and then retrieving the item at the first index. I was wondering if there was a faster way to grab an item without needing to convert to an array first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the first element of Set in ES6 ( EcmaScript 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539354/how-to-get-the-first-element-of-set-in-es6-ecmascript-2015) The answer provided there does consider the speed implications of its suggestion in its comments.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an iterator and get the value from the next call.

```js
console.log(new Set([1, 2, 3]).values().next().value);
```